# How can you detect runtime errors on flutter applications and log them while testing the app on iOS platform?

Tags: swift, flutter, plugins, error-handling, runtime-error

We tried to use speech recognition package - https://pub.dev/packages/speech_recognition in our flutter application along with other packages. The app was built successfully and installed, but we could see only a white screen on the iOS device. There was no error log that could tell us that this package created a problem. Once this module was removed we were able to see the application on the phone. This was done by manually checking for each package. I wanted to know if there is any runtime error handling methodology that could be used to log runtime errors and generate a logfile.

We are still researching on this issue, so we havent executed anything. Any suggestions would be welcome.